# Eclipse - passing VM parameter to every test in the project

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to pass a VM parameter to every test that is run in the project. Setting this manually doesn't seem to be the most convenient solution, so is there any possibility to pass the parameter to every test automatically.

Thank you for help.

Comment: What *kind* of test are you talking about? With JUnit all tests are executed in the same JVM, so there wouldn't be a special need to pass *vm arguments to every test*...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We change the JRE Configuration in Eclipse (Preferences>Java>Installed JREs). There you can set default VM Arguments which are used for anything you run with that JRE.

Now simply configure your project to use this JRE (Java Build Path) and you should be on the right way.

[image: Edit JRE - Eclipse]

Answer (score -1):

Eclipse have already a built-in JUnit for you.

You can use JUnit to run different parameters on your main program.

Comment: Yes I know, but I need this runer to be configured, so it takes automatically a specified parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Run your test once, this creates a run configuration.

Run-> Run Configurations -> JUnit, select your run configuration, then you have an arguments tab to specify JVM or program arguments.

You can then duplicate this run configuration to use for other tests. I'm not aware of any way to make a default setting to be applied to all future test launches.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using "Program Argument" instead of "VM argument" now. If you use VM argument it's mean globally applied to all of your tests.